# combining keyspace notification with keyevent notification

Tags: redis

I want to get a keyspace notification with a particular key and with a particular event.Like i want a notification when key name 'foo' is operated with a event 'set'.Is there any way to combine both the things like

```
psubscribe '__keyevent@0__,__keyspace@0__:set foo'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably no - you'll have to subscribe both to the events and the keyspace notifications and filter the messages in the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

```
K     Keyspace events, published with __keyspace@<db>__ prefix.
E     Keyevent events, published with __keyevent@<db>__ prefix.
g     Generic commands (non-type specific) like DEL, EXPIRE, RENAME, ...
$     String commands
l     List commands
s     Set commands
h     Hash commands
z     Sorted set commands
x     Expired events (events generated every time a key expires)
e     Evicted events (events generated when a key is evicted for maxmemory)
A     Alias for g$lshzxe, so that the "AKE" string means all the events.
```

At least `K` or `E` should be present in the string, otherwise no event will be delivered regardless of the rest of the string.
For instance to enable just Key-space events for lists, the configuration parameter must be set to Kl, and so forth.
The string `KEA` can be used to enable every possible event.